# Reference for a (non-standard) table of characteristic functions

Tags: reference-request, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I am searching for a table of characteristic functions of probability distributions with more than the standard distributions.

At a pinch a table of fourier transforms will do it too. But I computed specific characteristic functions and want to know if there is a known probability distribution corresponding to it.

An example could be: $\varphi (t) = \frac{1- e^{-\frac 1 2 t^2}}{\frac 1 2 t^2}$. (But for this I know the Fourierinversion already).

I expect having to compute more characteristic functions in future, and having a table for a quick check if it is known already could be a great help.

Comment: Might be useful to show us a sample.

Comment: You can take a book at the book by Ushakov on characteristic functions... in the appendix there is a list of characteristic functions.